# Finite measure such that $ν\ll μ$ and $μ\ll ν$ for $μ$ $σ$-finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

If $(X, \mathcal{A},μ)$ is σ-finite measurable space prove that $\exists ν$ finite measure in  $(X, \mathcal{A})$ such that $ν\llμ$ (absolutely continuous with respect to $μ$) and $μ\llν$.

I have no idea how to start. I thought of using the definition of singular measures but then I can't think of a suitable measure. Can someone help?

Comment: Break $A$ up into finite($\mu$) pieces and try to define $\nu$ on each piece.

Comment: @user10354138 You mean a random A in  σ-algebra?

Comment: Oops, should be $X$ not $A$.

Comment: TeX hint.  Use `\ll` to get $\mu \ll \nu$

Comment: Hint: By $\sigma$-finitenetness, there is a countable partition $A_n\in \mathcal{A}$ of $X$ such that $0<\mu(A_n)<\infty$. Define $f=\sum^\infty_{n=1}2^{-n}\frac{1}{\mu(A_n)}\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$. Notice $f>0$ and $\int_Xf\,d\mu<\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By σ-finitenetness, there is a countable partition $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ of $X$ such that $0<μ(A_n)< \infty$. Define $f= \sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{−n} \frac{1}{μ(A_n)}1_{A_n}$. Notice $f>0$ and $\int _{X}fdμ=\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{−n} \frac{1}{μ(A_n)} \int1_{A_n}dμ=\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{−n} =1< \infty$ where the first equality is from Beppo-Levi.

Then for $ν(A)=\int_{A} fdμ$ we know that $ν\llμ$ and if $ν(A)=0$ we have that $μ(A_n\cap A)=0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So $μ(Α)=0$ from subadditivity and $μ\ll ν$

Comment: The problem now is how to use that fact to construct a measure $\nu$ that is equivalent to $\mu$, i.e. $\mu\ll \nu$ and $\nu\ell \mu$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz But why is it a problem? If $ν(A)= \int_{A}fdμ$ I have what the exercise wanted.. Don't I?

Comment: All that remains is for you to show that $\nu=f\cdot\mu$ satisfies $\mu\ll\nu$. All that is easy, but you did not mentioned that in your solution.

Comment: Is $ν= f\cdot μ$ a symbol for $ν(A)=\int_{A} fdμ$. ?

Comment: Yes, it is. In any event, now it seems that you have a complete proof.